# Map function taking too much time (Pandas DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas Dataframe with the following shape: 12.000.000 x 2 (rows x columns) I need to apply a map function, however, it is taking so much time when it has to just compare every date of column 1 to a given date, for example, today.

Example of the DataFrame

```
╔════════════╦══════════╗
║    Col1    ║   Col2   ║
╠════════════╬══════════╣
║ 2019-03-19 ║        1 ║
║ 2019-03-20 ║        2 ║
║ 2019-05-15 ║        3 ║
║ 2019-07-15 ║        4 ║
║ ...        ║          ║
║ 2019-10-20 ║ 12000000 ║
╚════════════╩══════════╝
```

Example of the code

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('path_of_file.csv')
today = datetime.now()
df['output'] = df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > today else 0)
```

Am I missing something? Could it be improved? Thank you!

Comment: I am not an expert, but this link might be helpful: https://towardsdatascience.com/make-your-own-super-pandas-using-multiproc-1c04f41944a1

Comment: It is possible that it is loading the entire file into memory that is taking the time.  If perhaps you could read one line at a time to create your binary array then you wouldn't have to contain the entire input file in memory.  How long does it take to load versus to create the output array from the loaded data?

Comment: What is `Col1`'s dtype - `df.dtypes`?

Comment: How about just `df['output'] = 1 * df['Col1'] > today` ??

Comment: The numpy where function could help out : df['output'] = np.where(df.Col1>today,1,0)

Comment: @wwii I transformed the dtype to datetime using pd.to_datetime(df['Col1'])

Comment: @craig Hicks loading the data takes like a two minutes,  creating the output column +2hours

Comment: 2 hours vs 2 minutes!  I find that very surprising because IO access usually takes much longer than in-memory computation, unless RAM is insufficient and memory is actually being backed up on disk - a rare occurrence nowadays.  Does your system have RAM?  Is RAM used up by reading in the file?  The symptoms suggest "thrashing", where memory is repeatedly read from and written back to disk.  Sequential disk access is much faster than random access.

Comment: Are all the dates in column 1 just a day, month and year? It's not directly related to your question, but why use 0 and 1 for what is clearly a boolean value?

Comment: Any chance you have 120M rows and not 12M, otherwise I have no idea why it's taking hours. It should take minutes with the apply.

Comment: @AMC yep! the dates are year-month-date!

Comment: @ALollz pretty sure there are 12M rows!

Comment: _why use 0 and 1 for what is clearly a boolean value?_

Comment: @AMC After that, I'm going to sum all 1's. For given different dates!

Comment: @Snedecor You can sum booleans. Can you share a bit more information on that next step? It may be possible to count them in a more direct/efficient manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## EDIT - See wwii solution

wwii solution is the clear winner out of the OP's and mine.

His solution runs 2x faster than my own:

```
df['output'] = 1 * (df['Col1'] > today)
```

It's a pretty neat one too, as all you're doing is multiplying 1 with either 1 or 0, resulting in the truth value of comparing the date column with today's date.

---

This was a really interesting question, so I ran some tests on my end.

I created an empty dataframe with 1 million rows of dates.

```
starting_date = datetime(200, 1, 1, 00, 00)
end_date = datetime(3000,1, 1, 00, 00)
index = 1

date_values = []

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

date_values = [_date for _date in daterange(starting_date, end_date)]

date_col = {'Col1': date_values}
df = pd.DataFrame(date_col)
```

We're going into the future boys.

Now, the two tests I ran compared the function run time of the solution the OP provided, and the solution I posted below.

#### We are assuming the dates are in order

#### Test 1 - OP's solution

```
start_time = time.time()

df['output'] = df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > today else 0) 

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

#### Test 2 - My solution

```
start_time = time.time()

df['output'] = 1

df.loc[df['Col1'] < today, 'output'] = 0

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

#### The results

After running each function 10 times, the second solution won each time. Why? Honestly I have no idea.

I think we can make a good guess that under the hood, pandas is not performing a linear search when assigning a constant value to a column based on a condition, as demonstrated in the 2nd solution.

```
Soltuion 1
--- 0.36346006393432617 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.13942289352416992 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.4605379104614258 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.12388873100280762 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.34688305854797363 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.0912778377532959 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.2879600524902344 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.08435988426208496 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.3161609172821045 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.0965569019317627 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.31951212882995605 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.08857107162475586 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.2996959686279297 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.16647815704345703 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.5074219703674316 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.13281011581420898 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.3716299533843994 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.0970299243927002 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.29851794242858887 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.08089780807495117 seconds ---
```

Something to consider - the dates in both tests are in order. What happens if you receive them in complete, random order?

We first randomize the dataset:

```
df = df.sample(frac=1)
```

Then run the exact same tests.

```
Soltuion 1
--- 0.6548967361450195 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.22769808769226074 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.7096188068389893 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.28220510482788086 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.7588798999786377 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.25870585441589355 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.6285257339477539 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.3373727798461914 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.7623891830444336 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.18880391120910645 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.5125689506530762 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.23384499549865723 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.6188468933105469 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.25000977516174316 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.6692302227020264 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.5207180976867676 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 1.2534172534942627 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.2665679454803467 seconds ---
Soltuion 1
--- 0.6374101638793945 seconds ---
Solution 2
--- 0.2108619213104248 seconds ---
```

#### The solution

Since all you're doing is checking if the date is less than today's date, then create a new column and add a constant of either 1 or 0.

Lets first add the constant to the column.

```
df['Output'] = 1
```

Now, all we have to do is find the point where the date is less than the current date.

First though, we should change the date type of Col1 to a datetime, to make sure we can do proper comparisons.

```
df['Col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Col1'], format="%Y-%M-%d)
```

Then, we look through every date that's less than today, and change the output to 0.

```
df.loc[df['Col1'] < today.date(), 'Output'] = 0
```

Comment: Sorting is O(N log N) whereas the specified task is only O(N)

Comment: Good catch @CraigHicks. I've editted my answer after running some tests.

Comment: @ALollz would you mind providing your solution? Because OP is comparing an array with a scalar value. That is what apply is doing.

Comment: if you could run your comparison with different tables sizes (increasing by a factor of 2 each time) we can see if the times are growing linearly or if the OPs coding results in a higher than linear increase, in which case there is possibly a design flaw in the underlying implementation.

Comment: I'm going to try it! Thank you for the effort!

Comment: Well.. It took just seconds!! THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad it has helped!

Comment: I think `df['output'] = (df['Col1'] > today).astype(int)` would also work - how does it perform?

Comment: `(df.date > today).astype(np.int8)` seems to have a slight speed advantage.

Comment: That's another great nifty solution @wwii

Answer (score 1):

While we're still awaiting some more information on the problem, here is what I have so far:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "col_1": ["2019-03-19", "2019-03-20", "2030-01-01", "2019-05-15", "2019-07-15"],
        "col_2": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    }
)

df["col_1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["col_1"], infer_datetime_format=True, utc=True)

print(df, end='\n\n')

curr_time = pd.Timestamp.utcnow()

print(curr_time, end='\n\n')

df["col_3"] = df["col_1"] > curr_time

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                      col_1  col_2
0 2019-03-19 00:00:00+00:00      1
1 2019-03-20 00:00:00+00:00      2
2 2030-01-01 00:00:00+00:00      3
3 2019-05-15 00:00:00+00:00      4
4 2019-07-15 00:00:00+00:00      5

2020-02-12 02:11:37.212849+00:00

                      col_1  col_2  col_3
0 2019-03-19 00:00:00+00:00      1  False
1 2019-03-20 00:00:00+00:00      2  False
2 2030-01-01 00:00:00+00:00      3   True
3 2019-05-15 00:00:00+00:00      4  False
4 2019-07-15 00:00:00+00:00      5  False
```